# Error connecting to the service protocol: No Flutter view is available

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

As i run flutter project (flutter run) in android studio..
Application is built in device resulting connection loss .. this happens most of the time ..

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       125.8s (!)
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                38.7s
Error connecting to the service protocol: No Flutter view is available on Redmi Note 3.
```

I'm on flutter channel master*

```
Flutter channels:
* master
  dev
  beta
  stable
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.18.0-9.0.pre.73, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.778], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.18.0-9.0.pre.73 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision bd6ccb606a (35 hours ago), 2020-04-29 16:31:42 -0700
    • Engine revision 2db3276573
    • Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-4.0.dev 726d3c7725)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ABHIJEET\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\ABHIJEET\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: D:\installs\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at D:\installs\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Redmi Note 3 • 57abce51   • android-arm64  • Android 6.0.1 (API 23)
    • Web Server   • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome       • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 81.0.4044.129

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

Running for Second time resolves the error , but still I don't understand why most of time error occurs resulting connection loss to the device.